# 2 inputs to a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So Ive been giving the following code in a kind of sort of python class. Its really a discrete math class but he uses python to demonstrate everything. This code is supposed to demonstate a multiplexer and building a xor gate with it.

```
def mux41(i0,i1,i2,i3):
    return lambda s1,s0:{(0,0):i0,(0,1):i1,(1,0):i2,(1,1):i3}[(s1,s0)]

def xor2(a,b):
    return mux41(0,1,1,0)(a,b)
```

In the `xor2` function I dont understand the syntax behind `return mux41(0,1,1,0)(a,b)` the 1's and 0's are the input to the mux function, but what is the (a,b) doing?

Comment: read about higher order function's. this pdf use's them in python http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.01/spring08/handouts/week2/week2-notes.pdf.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `(a, b)` is actually the input to the `lambda` function that you return in the `mux41` function.

Your `mux41` function returns a `lambda` function which looks like it returns a value in a dictionary based on the input to the `mux41` function. You need the second input to say which value you want to return.

It is directly equivalent to:

```
def xor2(a,b):
    f = mux41(0,1,1,0)
    return f(a,b)
```

Comment: +1, I hope you don't mind, added an example that I think clarifies it a little.

Comment: @Lattyware Thanks. I also added an explanation of why the second input is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

That is fairly advanced code to throw at Python beginners, so don't feel bad it wasn't obvious to you.  I also think it is rather trickier than it needs to be.

```
def mux41(i0,i1,i2,i3):
    return lambda s1,s0:{(0,0):i0,(0,1):i1,(1,0):i2,(1,1):i3}[(s1,s0)]
```

This defines a function object that returns a value based on two inputs.  The two inputs are `s1` and `s0`.  The function object builds a dictionary that is pre-populated with the four values passed int to `mux41()`, and it uses `s0` and `s1` to select one of those four values.

Dictionaries use keys to look up values.  In this case, the keys are Python tuples: `(0, 0)`, `(0, 1)`, `(1, 0)`, and `(1,1)`.  The expression `(s1,s0)` is building a tuple from the arguments `s0` and `s1`.  This tuple is used as the key to lookup a value from the dictionary.

```
def xor2(a,b):
    return mux41(0,1,1,0)(a,b)
```

So, `mux41()` returns a function object that does the stuff I just discussed.  `xor2()` calls `mux41()`  and gets a function object; then it immediately calls that returned function object, passing in `a` and `b` as arguments.  Finally it returns the answer.

The function object created by `mux41()` is not saved anywhere.  So, every single time you call `xor2()`, you are creating a function object, which is then garbage collected.  When the function object runs, it builds a dictionary object, and this too is garbage collected after each single use.  This is possibly the most complicated XOR function I have ever seen.

Here is a rewrite that might make this a bit clearer.  Instead of using `lambda` to create an un-named function object, I'll just use `def` to create a named function.

```
def mux41(i0,i1,i2,i3):
    def mux_fn(s1, s0):
        d = {
            (0,0):i0,
            (0,1):i1,
            (1,0):i2,
            (1,1):i3
        }
        tup = (s1, s0)
        return d[tup]
    return mux_fn

def xor2(a,b):
    mux_fn = mux41(0,1,1,0)
    return mux_fn(a,b)
```

EDIT: Here is what I would have written if I wanted to make a table-lookup XOR in Python.

```
_d_xor2 = {
    (0,0) : 0,
    (0,1) : 1,
    (1,0) : 1,
    (1,1) : 0
}

def xor2(a,b):
    tup = (a, b)
    return _d_xor2[tup]
```

We build the lookup dictionary once, then use it directly from `xor2()`.  It's not really necessary to make an explicit temp variable in `xor2()` but it might be a bit clearer.  You could just do this:

```
def xor2(a,b):
    return _d_xor2[(a, b)]
```

Which do you prefer?

And of course, since Python has an XOR operator built-in, you could write it like this:

```
def xor2(a,b):
    return a ^ b
```

If I were writing this for real I would probably add error handling and/or make it operate on `bool` values.

```
def xor2(a,b):
    return bool(a) ^ bool(b)
```

EDIT: One more thing just occurred to me.  In Python, the rule is "the comma makes the tuple".  The parentheses around a tuple are sometimes optional.  I just checked, and it works just fine to leave off the parentheses in a dictionary lookup.  So you can do this:

```
def xor2(a,b):
    return _d_xor2[a, b]
```

And it works fine.  This is perhaps a bit too tricky?  If I saw this in someone else's code, it would surprise me.

Comment: "This is possibly the most complicated XOR function I have ever seen." - you're not the only one.

Comment: Something that might be interesting to note is that the `d` dict you make in your first example could be moved out of the inner function, so it would only need to be calculated once, rather than each time the inner function is called. You can also reuse the value returned from `mux41`, rather than calling it over and over. Using `xor2 = mux41(0, 1, 1, 0)` would work, and you could do other operations in the same way, e.g. `and2 = mux41(1, 0, 0, 0)` and `or2 = mux41(1, 1, 1, 0)`. This is still a rather complicated way to get binary operators, but it's not entirely useless complexity.